# Please give examples of countably-infinite matrices that are Hermitian &/or invertible, & that correspond to operators commonly encountered in physics

Tags: mathematical-physics, infinite-matrices

I'm new to quantum mechanics, and I believe that understanding infinite vector spaces should help my understanding of the math involved.  Most of the time I'm only dealing with infinitely differentiable functions that also have a Taylor Series expansion, and I *believe* this implies that {$1, x^2, x^3, x^4, ... $} serves as a basis of cardinality $|\Bbb{N}|$ for the vector space of all such functions, and that therefore even though these functions live in a $|\Bbb{R}|$-dimensional space, they can still be restricted to a $|\Bbb{N}|$-dimensional space, similar to how vectors restricted to a 2D plane also can live in a 3D space.  Please give examples of countably-infinite matrices that are Hermitian &/or invertible, & that correspond to operators commonly encountered in physics.  Thanks!

Comment: In general, in physics, your space "has a basis of cardinality $|\Bbb{N}|$" and  "has a basis of cardinality $|\Bbb{R}|$" at the same time. Like summables functions on $|\Bbb{R}|$.

Comment: There is then, translation or more generally composition with an other function, or multiplication by an other function that are "infinite matrices". There may be condition on the function you multiply with, to keep the regularity of your function.